# iOS 6 iAd property and methods deprecated

Tags: ios, iad, deprecated, ios6

Since iOS 6 release, there are some iAd properties and methods that are deprecated like :

```
currentContentSizeIdentifier
requiredContentSizeIdentifiers
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape
```

So what's the best way to implement iAd now on both orientation ? Should we now resize the banner view frame manually ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have my application only support Landscape mode(should work for Portrait mode also), and have iAd showing up on the top of the application.  And to make this work with ios6 I had to do this:

**In Monotouch**

```
storesAdBannerView = new ADBannerView();
storesAdBannerView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
```

For objc (which I dont use), I think it might be

```
[storesAdBannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]
```

Comment: Oh yea you're right, it works pretty easily with AutoresizingMask !

Comment: NO. This does not work. If you removed those deprecated lines of code and added NOTHING it would still work just as good as the solution above. This seemed to fix the issue because you were using `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait`. If you were using landscape this would have broken your app.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that landscape ads are somewhat phased out.
See: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/108118-landscape-iad-banners-in-ios-6-edit-landscape-phased-out-completely.html

It need further confirmation, as I could not find any Apple document regarding that change.

Comment: Yeah i'm pretty surprized there are no alternatives of these deprecations in Apple doc :/

Comment: The developer forums say that this is not correct, and that landscape ads are still supported in iOS6: https://devforums.apple.com/message/755532#755532

I am able to get them working on an iPhone 5, but the iPad is always showing 768 width and not 1024 when in landscape..

Answer (score 1):

I sAw 2 workaround there : http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/iad-code-is-broken-in-ios6/  Tested the first solution:

easy temporary solution – you can quickly get your app to compile again by using a cheap cheat, add explicitly #import  to the files where you are accessing currentContentSizeIdentifier and the size name constants. That should get you going until you alter your app to use the new auto-layout features.

It works ok on xcode 4.5 (banner test ok).