# How to change content size of ADBannerView in iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

`currentContentSizeIdentifier` is deprecated in iOS6. I tried

```
_adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

But it only works in iOS4/5.

How to change content size of ADBannerView in iOS6?

Special thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[_adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight]
```

Hope it will help.

for more information:

[iOS 6 iAd property and methods deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557566/ios-6-iad-property-and-methods-deprecated)

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/16/placing-iad-banners-at-the-top-of-a-table-view.html