# Need help at Ad SDK (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, sdk, iad

i downloaded a project with iAD Examples.
Now i have a few problems.

Need i a iAD SDK? Where can i download it?

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait'
```

or

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait'
Property 'requiredContentSizeIdentifiers' not found on object of type 'ADBannerView *'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad iAd.framework in to your project. This removes all linker errors related to iAds.

Notes:

**« ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait**  is DEPRECATED in **iOS6**

« Refer proposed answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557566/ios-6-iad-property-and-methods-deprecated)
[image]

Comment: I have added that ^^ "iAd.framework" -> "required". In the finder he shows the iAd content, too... it exists... Include per #import "iAd/ADBannerView.h"